# stack smashing detected followed by segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets, scanf, ps

I'm a newbie. I need to print the details of all process on the system. I have redirected the output of `"ps -aux"` to a text file and opened it in-order to display. Though I get the required details displayed correctly, I get stack smashing error and then segmentation fault. I could understand the segmentation fault is from one of the `fgets`/`sscanf` functions. May I know where might have I went wrong?

```
if ( NULL != ( FileDesc = fopen( FileName , "r" ) ) )
{
     if( ! fgets(buf, sizeof( buf ), FileDesc) )
           {
                Status = -1;
           }

    while( NULL != fgets( buf, sizeof( buf ), FileDesc ) )
    {
        sscanf( buf, "%*s %d %*s %s %*d %*d %*s %s %*s %s %[^\n] ",
                     &(ProcVar[CurrProcessNum].Pid),
                     &(ProcVar[CurrProcessNum].Size),
                     (ProcVar[CurrProcessNum].State),
                     (ProcVar[CurrProcessNum].CpuTime),
                     (ProcVar[CurrProcessNum].Cmd));
        printf (" PID: %d size: %s State: %s CpuTime: %s Cmd %s",
                               (ProcVar[CurrProcessNum].Pid),
                               (ProcVar[CurrProcessNum].Size),
                               (ProcVar[CurrProcessNum].State),
                               (ProcVar[CurrProcessNum].CpuTime),
                               (ProcVar[CurrProcessNum].Cmd));
        CurrProcessNum ++;
    }
}
```

Sample output is :

```
PID: 21342 size: 0.0 State: S CpuTime: 0:00 Cmd [kjournald]
PID: 23384 size: 2.6 State: Sl CpuTime: 39:59 Cmd /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread /root/Documents/Comcast_RDK2.0-B13.4_Broadcom_release_notes_20140123.pdf
PID: 23495 size: 0.9 State: Ssl CpuTime: 9:01 Cmd gnome-terminal
PID: 23498 size: 0.0 State: S CpuTime: 0:00 Cmd gnome-pty-helper
PID: 23499 size: 0.0 State: Ss CpuTime: 0:00 Cmd bash
PID: 26733 size: 0.1 State: Ss CpuTime: 0:18 Cmd sshd: root@pts/3
PID: 26843 size: 0.2 State: Ss CpuTime: 0:01 Cmd -bash
PID: 26943 size: 0.1 State: Ss CpuTime: 0:06 Cmd sshd: root@notty
PID: 27052 size: 0.0 State: Ss CpuTime: 0:00 Cmd /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
PID: 29510 size: 0.0 State: S CpuTime: 0:00 Cmd su root
PID: 29517 size: 0.1 State: S+ CpuTime: 0:04 Cmd bash
PID: 29951 size: 0.1 State: S+ CpuTime: 1:06 Cmd minicom
PID: 30056 size: 0.0 State: Ss+ CpuTime: 0:00 Cmd bash
PID: 30293 size: 0.0 State: Ss CpuTime: 0:00 Cmd bash
PID: 30329 size: 0.0 State: S+ CpuTime: 0:01 Cmd ssh root@192.168.70.54
PID: 30597 size: 0.0 State: Ss CpuTime: 0:00 Cmd bash
PID: 30632 size: 0.0 State: S+ CpuTime: 0:00 Cmd ssh root@192.168.70.54
PID: 31508 size: 0.0 State: Ss+ CpuTime: 0:00 Cmd bash
PID: 31522 size: 0.1 State: Ss+ CpuTime: 0:00 Cmd bash
*** stack smashing detected ***: bin/TR69_DM terminated
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: The initial `fgets()` makes no sense, are you skipping a header or something? Also, show more declarations. Perhaps `CurrProcessNum` is going out of range of `ProcVar`?

Comment: stack smashing means that the contents of stack frame of caller was somehow changed by callee. that's a security prevention against buffer overflows

Comment: You're probably exceeding the array-size of `ProcVar`, to which you are continually incrementing the index into.

Comment: `sscanf` might be exceeded argument for format specifier also what is size of array `ProcVar[?]`? might be index cause out of bound

Comment: The best tool to investigate this is `valgrind`.

Comment: What are the types of the various fields of `ProcVar[]`? Methinks you are reading *strings* into *integers*, with predictable results. Compile with *all* relevant compiler warnings enabled, and a modest optimization level (many warnings rely on information the copmpiler collects only when optimizing).

Comment: @unwind yes. the first fgets is to eat up the header..I tried printing the value of CurrProcessNum .But it is in the range of ProcVar.

Comment: @mangusta Is there any way to deal with it? Can I avoid any changes? I only intend to save the values to contents, passed to the function.

Comment: @noelicus I think I checked if its exceeding the array limit and it is verified.

Comment: @vonbrand  The structure contains the following fields struct ProcessInfo
{
    char ProcName[CHAR_BUF_SIZE];
    char Cmd[CHAR_BUF_SIZE];
    char CpuTime[CHAR_BUF_SIZE];
    int32_t Pid;
    int32_t Priority;
    char Size[CHAR_BUF_SIZE];
    char State[CHAR_BUF_SIZE];

};

Comment: @ChristyGeorge please add the structure to the question as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

@vonbrand Please see the fields of the structure

```
   struct ProcessInfo { 
 char ProcName[CHAR_BUF_SIZE];
 char Cmd[CHAR_BUF_SIZE]; 
 char CpuTime[CHAR_BUF_SIZE];
 int32_t Pid;
 int32_t Priority;
 char Size[CHAR_BUF_SIZE];
 char State[CHAR_BUF_SIZE];
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've shown (which is still not enough for us to go on btw!) you're overwriting the stack with either (or perhaps both) of:

1. You exceed the `ProcVar` array size as you don't check for array
   bounds
   (i.e. that `CurrProcessNum < elements in the array`)
2. One of
   the strings you read into your array exceeds the length of
   `CHAR_BUF_SIZE`. To get around this you could utilise a safe version
   of sscanf. Microsoft have a [safe sscanf called sscanf_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6z7bya3.aspx) where
   you pass the buffer sizes in after the buffer argument. Or you could
   try and ditch sscanf altogether. Or use bigger buffers then copy
   *those* into your array using a safe string copy (e.g. `strncpy`).